# bootstrap 4 nested column not stacking

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

new to bootstrap and experimenting on a pet project. am a bit at my wits ends here.

my understanding is if you have `<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5">` and `<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-7 ">` on small screen each would take a new row (12 cols). vs on a large screen they'd share the row (5+7). in my code the second table(fruits) is supposed to share row with the chart on large screens and split on small screen but when I try small screens in debugging mode, the second column with the chart gets pushed out of the parent column (off screen). I have no clue what exactly is wrong here. any help would be appreciated
bellow is a portion of the code

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="media content-section col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label class="switch"
        ><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" />
        <div class="slider round">
          <!--ADDED HTML --><span class="on">BUY</span
          ><span class="off">SELL</span
          ><!--END-->
        </div></label
      >
      <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered tableformat">
          <thead>
            SUMMARY
            <small class="text-muted"
              >(edit cells to adjust position)</small
            >
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">col 1</th>
              <th scope="col">col 2</th>
              <th scope="col">col 3</th>
              <th scope="col">col 4</th>
              <th scope="col">col 5</th>
              <th scope="col">col 6</th>
              <th scope="col">col 7</th>
              <th scope="col">col 8</th>
              <th scope="col">col 9</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>0</td>
              <td width="60">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  maxlength="10"
                  width="50%"
                  placeholder="1"
                  size="10"
                />
              </td>
              <td width="60">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  maxlength="10"
                  width="50%"
                  size="10"
                  placeholder="2"
                />
              </td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            type="submit"
          >
            update position
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            type="submit"
          >
            reset to default
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="media content-section col-sm-12-col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5">
      <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table
          class="table table-sm table-bordered tableformat text-center"
        >
          <thead>
            fruits
            <small class="text-muted"
              >(hover on terms for quick definitions)</small
            >
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">mango</th>
              <th scope="col">banana</th>
              <th scope="col">apple</th>
              <th scope="col">peach</th>
              <th scope="col">grapes</th>
              <th scope="col">lemon</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chart col-sm-12 col-lg-7 overflow-auto">
      <div style="width: 560; height: 400;">
        <canvas id="plchart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is how it looks in debugging mode on [large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P79Gn.jpg) vs on [small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xiN1.jpg). I have in the meta tag  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

solved it. I missed the inner row before the cols.
essentially should be something like container->row->outer col->inner row -> inner-cols. I was doing container->row-> outer col -> inner cols